# pdo registration page error when trying to register a sample user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, load, registration

Hello i am working on creating a user registration page. I believe i have tried everything, when i try to test the registration page it just reloads the same page. when i click the submit 
button and doesn't go into my database nor shows the "your account has been created". I have even tried using deprecated MySQL code but it fails as well. Keep in mind that this is just a bare bones set of code and has not been styled using CSS at all.
here is the code...

```
<?php
include("/scripts/connectionfile.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']."ALS52KAO089");
$confpassword = md5($_POST['conpassword']."ALS52KAO089");
}
    if(isset($email, $username, $password, $confPassword)){
        if(strstr($email, "@")){
            if($password == $confPassword){
                $query = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
                $query = $query->execute(array(
                    $username,
                    $email
                ));
                $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($count == '0'){
                    $query = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET username = ?, email = ?, password = ?");
                    $query = $query->execute(array(
                        $username,
                        $email,
                        $password
                        ));
                    if($query){
                            echo "Your account has been created, you may now login!";

                        }

                }else{  
                    echo "A user already exist with that name."; 
                }
            }else{
                echo "Your passwords do not match!";
            }   
            }else{
                echo "Invalid email address!";
            }
        }


?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table>

<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><Input type="text" name="email"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><Input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Confirm Password:</td>
    <td><Input type="password" name="conpassword"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Here is my connection code

```
        <?php
$user ="root";
$pass = "";
$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users", $user, $pass);


?>
```

Comment: You would get more people willing to help if you pasted your code directly into your post instead of linking to a screenshot.

Comment: I do apologize, extremely new to the site but i got it formatted right now so if you can help i would be greatful.

Comment: What is on your `connectionfile.php`?

Comment: You can not mix pdo and mysql_ functions. Your row count won't work.

Comment: what is the correct pdo code for the row count i couldn't find it.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, `PDO` row count is not accurate on some databases when using the row count and `SELECT`. The proper way is to use a `COUNT(*)` statement.

Comment: im not familiar with that statement, i hate to ask but could you show me the proper way to implement it in place of my current one.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to implement it all in one statement but count is something like this: `"SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?"` You would get `$result['count']`

Comment: Actually, the way you are using it you just need the count statement now that I reread what you are doing.

Comment: Your insert statement is an update statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the changes I have outlined below:

```
<?php
include("/scripts/connectionfile.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        function get_user_count($username = false,$email = false,$con = false)
            {
                if($username != false && $email != false && $con != false) {
                        $query  =   $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
                        $query->execute(array($username,$email));
                        $result =   $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                        if($result['count'] == 1)
                            return true;
                    }

                return false;
            }

        // Use a better validate
        $creds['email']         =   (filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))? $_POST['email']:false;
        // Check it's not empty
        $creds['username']      =   (!empty($_POST['username']))? $_POST['username']:false;
        // You should be using a proper encryption. md5 is not good enough, even with a salt
        $creds['password']      =   (!empty($_POST['password']))? md5($_POST['password']."ALS52KAO089"):false;
        $creds['conpassword']   =   (!empty($_POST['conpassword']))? md5($_POST['conpassword']."ALS52KAO089"):false;

        if(!in_array(false,$creds)) {
                // You were trying to match $conpassword and $conPassword
                // Notice the P in confp and confP
                if($creds['password'] == $creds['conpassword']){
                    if(get_user_count($creds['username'],$creds['email'],$dbc) == false){
                        // Your statement is a mix of insert and update
                        $query  =   $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                        // Swicht $query to $result
                        $result =   $query->execute(array($creds['username'],$creds['email'],$creds['password']));

                        if($result)
                            $error  =   "Your account has been created, you may now login!";

                    }else  
                        $error  =   "A user already exist with that name."; 
                }else
                    $error  =   "Your passwords do not match!";

        }else
            $error  =   "Invalid email address!";

        echo $error;
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><Input type="text" name="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><Input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
            <td><Input type="password" name="conpassword"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok i worked around with the code you gave me and overhauled mine but now i am getting an "invalid email" when i am attempting a sample user and i am using a correct email

Comment: I have revised mine a bit since you copied it

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I had a couple copy issues. Try now.

Comment: now im getting a user with that name already exist, checked my database and no users are registered

Comment: Ok so in the function, just check the return on the count with `print_r($result);` See what that says

Comment: Oh wait, that one line should register as `== false` not `!= false` I will revise. I forgot you wanted to insert on false. Should be good now.

Comment: I fixed it you had the result value set wrong ! Thanks though you were a ton of help! upvoted!

Comment: i cant upvote your post, not enough rep

Comment: Well the result would be `true` if user is in system I had the above mentioned wrong `== false` rather than `!= false`

Comment: Make sure you mark it as answered or you will get others coming thinking it's not yet answered.

Comment: oh i just seen the button to do that lol! such a newbie to this site